# document.createElement('a').click() not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a function that retrieves arraybuffer data from my API, creates a temporary anchor on the page and then clicks it in order to download the file.

The function works as expected in Chrome.

```
@action
  async loadVoucher(id, fiscalId) {
    const pdf = await this.httpClient.get(...);

    console.log("load Voucher: ", pdf);

    const blob = new Blob([pdf.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = "Dossier_" + new Date() + ".pdf";

    console.log("before link click");

    link.click();
    link.remove();
  }
```

The `@action` decorator comes from mobx. In firefox the second console.log - before click link gets logged to the browser console (the first log also logs my data correctly), but the download does not start.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox, you need to add the created element to the DOM and it will work:

```
<div class="button" id="test">Create File</div>

    $('body').on('click', '#test', function(event) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        // Add the element to the DOM
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.setAttribute("type", "hidden"); // make it hidden if needed
        link.download = 'test.xls';
        link.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;utf-8,test';
        link.click();
    });
```

codepen - http://jsfiddle.net/b40af6rm/